# Android Layout with overlapping view

Tags: android

I want to create a Layout with two groups of views: group 1 is a linear layout with vertical direction that contains several image views, group 2 is a simple frame layout with just one image view. Now I would like to put group 1 on top of group 2 (overlapped), and align the center (red dot) of first image view of group 1 and group 2, how can I achieve this in one xml layout file? I made a mock for the view, see picture below

[Mock view of the description above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f4He.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use powerful **RelativeLayout**:

```
<RelativeLayout 
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/group_1"
        android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                  android:text="View 1"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                  android:text="View 2"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
                  android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                  android:text="View 3"/>
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
                  android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                  android:text="View 4"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/group_2"
    android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="150dp"
               android:scaleType="fitXY"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]